# In Editor: Ctrl+F find box, config to search only on Enter?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, settings

In VS2013, I find it irritating that it jumps wildly through the current source file to places matching my incomplete entry, while I am typing - I would prefer if it did nothing at all until I completed my entry and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (and if it finds nothing, the scroll position in the file will not be changed).

I couldn't find an option under "Tools/Options..." that looks like it helps there.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no user setting for that, sadly.

Instead, however, consider using SHIFT CTRL+F (find in files). Not the obvious choice, but I've started to prefer it as it gets rid of the leaping about and it can anyway be useful to see the list of occurrences before losing scroll position (whether or not it finds anything).